# Issue with replacing hexadecimal escape sequences in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, hex, escaping

I'm trying to fix a string which has some encoding characters in it.

I thought I should be able to match the hex characters of the special characters and convert them back to a normal character.

Here is my example code:

```
let str = "url('https\3a //');";
str = str.replace(/\x5C\x33\x61\x20/g,":"); // equivalent to '\3a '
console.log(str);
```

I expected the output to be `url('https://');` but I actually got `url('https a //');`

What am I missing? [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/alexbfree/mfs51zcn/15/). Is this some sort of multi byte character issue? I looked at the resulting string in a hex editor and the replaced characters seem to be `\x03\x61\x20` rather than the expected `\x3A`.

EDIT: why has this been down voted? It is a fair question isn't it?

Comment: Do you have a `'\3a'` or `'\\3a'` in the real data?

Comment: You can just match the actual characters: `str.replace(/\3a /g,":")` works fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : `\3a`. I believe `\\` is necessary in regex to specify you need an actual slash.

Comment: There is no actual or non-actual slash. There exists a literal backslash, a symbol present in text, and there is a representation of a backslash in a string literal. So, ``\`` is written as `"\\"` and a newline is written as `"\n"` and a char with octal value `1` is written as `'\1'`... So, what *literal text* you have got?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's hard to judge what is literally present because I am getting it from the code inspector inside someone else's webpage, but when I copy and paste it, it pastes as `https\3a //`

Comment: @Gavin It seems you are correct, but I cannot understand why. According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) I *should* need to prefix the backslash with a second backslash in order to match it. I am not sure why I am needing to do the opposite in this case!

Comment: Do not trust any code inspector. What is the real text? You already see where you are going wrong, right?

Comment: I can think of no other option but using code inspector, as the URL encoding is done by the platform I am trying to modify (within a web extension), the text is not displayed on screen and I don't have source code access. Anyway no worries, have gone with @Gavin's approach for now, even though I am not sure why it works.

Answer (score -1):

Is the code that you use really needs to be in this form?
I got the desired result using "3a".

```html
str = "url('https\3a //');";
str = str.replace(/\3a /g,":"); // equivalent to '\3a '
console.log(str);

//result: url('https://');
```

Comment: I think that the way you do this would have worked if the exact symbols \x5C\x33\x61\x20 were encoded in the string. But in your case the symbol that is encoded is \3a and I think that it should be referenced this way.

Comment: OK. it is odd that the starting string is modified then, rather than just failure to find a match. That doesn't make sense to me....